# Pressing and Holding a key in LWJGL

Tags: java, keyboard, key, lwjgl, tapandhold

I am using LWJGL and I want to cause an event to rapidly take place when I press and hold a key (like holding a letter key in word).

This is my attempt:

```
while(Keyboard.next())
{
    if (Keyboard.getEventKeyState())
    {
        if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_UP)) 
        {
            i += 5.0f;
        }
        if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_RIGHT)) 
        {
            i -= 1.0f;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answered my own question by using a robot and a thread when pressed:

```
        if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_DOWN))
        {
            Robot robot = new Robot();
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);
            zpos -= 0.1f;
            Thread.sleep(100);
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

`if (Keyboard.getEventKeyState())` only runs when a key is pressed.

For holding down, use a boolean/integer to record whether your game loop should increase or decrease `i`.